# PDO get result index by column name

Tags: php, pdo

suppose i have a simple table like

name | email
a  |  a@a.com
b  |  b@b.com

If i do

```
$result = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

on a SELECT * for example, I get something like

```
Array{  
   [0] => array{  
            ['name'] => 'a'  
            ['email'] => 'a@a.com'  
         }  
   [1] => array{  
            ['name'] => 'b'  
            ['email'] => 'b@b.com' 
         }  
    }
```

I would want something like

```
Array{
    ['name'] => Array{
               [0] => 'a'
               [1] => 'b'
              }
    ['email'] => Array{
               [0] => 'a@a.com'
               [1] => 'b@b.com'
              }
}
```

So that $result['name'] is an array with all the names. I know i can write a very small function to do that myself. Just wondering if there was some fetch_style parameter that would do that automatically.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this can be done with any of the fetch styles.

Comment: It can't be done in a single query. The most interesting part of PDO to look at would be "PDO::FETCH_COLUMN". However, there is no way to return another column from the same row if you use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it with any PDO flags.
Here' my suggested converting script, it's very small:

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $arr) foreach($arr as $k=>$v) $result[$k][] = $v;

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do that.

You can use `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` as suggested [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> To return an associative array grouped by the values of a specified column, bitwise-OR PDO::FETCH_COLUMN with PDO::FETCH_GROUP.

This flag will index by first column of your select, you only have to move your wanted indexed field to position 0.